# Reset local git repo to exactly that of remote?

Tags: git

Reset local git repo to exactly that of remote?

What is the best way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

reset to the last commit in remote `git reset HEAD --hard`

replace HEAD with the latest remote commit if it isn't head

then clean out everything else `git clean -fd`

Comment: Adding the `-x` flag to git clean also removes any files that are listed in the .gitignore file : `git clean -fdx`

Comment: Thanks! `git clean -fd` removes my unwanted 'untracked files' :)

Answer (score 1):

The simplest is probably to simply clone the remote repository again.

Comment: Save your local `config` etc. settings first though.

Comment: I'd just clone somewhere else to keep both (and only discard the original after a while (and a backup)).

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
git pull
```

but becare that this will merge your local branch to the state of the remote branch at the same time.

If no, that a fast-forward merge will be done and that's what you need